# Accessing a remote web service with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, jsonp

I'm developing a mobile application which requires access to a certain remote web service. I'm using jQuery.ajax(), and because of the the same origin policy, I'm forced to do my request using JSONP. 
My client request is so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.foo.jws/bar",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'jsonp', 

    success: function(msg) {
       console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error');
    }

});
```

The error I keep receiving is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

What am I doning wrong?

**EDIT:** The data in the WS is in XML

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a function here.

```
error: function() {
    console.log('error');
}
```

Also, take out the trailing comma.

Comment: Thanks, but I just copied it wrong from my text editor. I fixed the original post. I wish it was only that...

Comment: The trailing comma you saw was most likely the cause of the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error.

Comment: @user1575127: The problem is probably the JSON itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your error callback code is incorrect.  I'm not sure if this was just because you typed the code in here, or copy/pasted it.  Should be:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error');
}
```

You can then get some more information about what's going on with your call from the arguments that come into the error callback.

Edit:  Okay, since you're getting XML back from the server, you need to change dataType from jsonp to xml.  The dataType option tells jQuery what type of data to expect on the return.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.foo.jws/bar",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'xml', 
    success: function(msg) {
       console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: passing the parameters in the error function, I did get more information. textStatus= parsererror, errorThrown= Error: jQuery17104335657299961895_1344027946662 was not called.
Still not sure how to proceed from that.

Comment: Do you know if the ajax call is even getting to the remote server?

Comment: well, checking the console, the origin of the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' is from the remote server, so I'm guessing that the call gets to it fine.